# Multi level lookup values in dataframe with nested data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

The different Red colors (row 1-3) are grouped together in group "Dark Red". They are part of the "Red" group (7-8) and the "Dark" group (14-16). The "Red" group (7-8) references an additional group: "Color" (11-13).

---

The goal is to get a list of all referenced group for each "Value".

**Example:**

Input: `"Scarlet Red"`

Expected Output: `['Scarlet Red', 'Dark Red', 'Red', 'Dark', 'Color']`

---

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID': {0: 'P1',  1: 'C1',  2: 'C2',  3: 'P2',  4: 'C3',  5: 'C4',  6: 'L1',  7: 'P1',  8: 'L2',  9: 'P2',  10: 'LL1',  11: 'L1',  12: 'L2',  13: 'D1',  14: 'P1',  15: 'P2'}, 'Values': {0: 'Dark Red',  1: 'Scarlet Red',  2: 'Cherry Red',  3: 'Dark Blue',  4: 'Steel Blue',  5: 'Coral Blue',  6: 'Red',  7: 'Dark Red',  8: 'Blue',  9: 'Dark Blue',  10: 'Color',  11: 'Red',  12: 'Blue',  13: 'Dark',  14: 'Dark Red',  15: 'Dark Blue'}, 'Type': {0: 'Preferred',  1: 'Name',  2: 'Name',  3: 'Preferred',  4: 'Name',  5: 'Name',  6: 'Preferred',  7: 'Name',  8: 'Preferred',  9: 'Name',  10: 'Preferred',  11: 'Name',  12: 'Name',  13: 'Preferred',  14: 'Name',  15: 'Name'}, 'Group': {0: 1,  1: 1,  2: 1,  3: 2,  4: 2,  5: 2,  6: 3,  7: 3,  8: 4,  9: 4,  10: 5,  11: 5,  12: 5,  13: 6,  14: 6,  15: 6}, 'Level': {0: 0,  1: 0,  2: 0,  3: 0,  4: 0,  5: 0,  6: 1,  7: 1,  8: 1,  9: 1,  10: 2,  11: 2,  12: 2,  13: 1,  14: 1,  15: 1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Current approach:**

```
# get the preferred names
df_pref =  df[df['Type'].eq('Preferred')][['Values', 'Group']].rename(columns={'Values': 'Preferred'})
df_merge = df.merge(df_pref, on=['Group'], how='left')

def find_higher_levels(search):
    # search = 'Scarlet Red'
    lst = [search]
    previous_search = None
    while search != previous_search:
        previous_search = search
        search = df_merge[df_merge['Values'].eq(search)]['Preferred'].iloc[-1]
        lst.append(search)
    return lst

find_higher_levels('Scarlet Red')
# Out[85]: ['Scarlet Red', 'Dark Red', 'Dark', 'Dark']
```

Note: Even if the function would work as expected I would have to map it to each Value in 'Values'. My question is if there is a smarter approach to this.

Comment: Is there a reason all this data is in a dataframe?  Typically a dataframe should be pretty semantically flat.  If it's not semantically flat, it's not easy to work with the nesting.  It seems like you have nested data here.

Comment: @KyleParsons, good point, I am open to suggestions. The reason is that there are multiple similar tables (but not as deeply nested as this one) which is why I wanted to have a similar format, but this is not a hard requirement.

Comment: @KyleParsons found a solution which works for a dataframe. See below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the `networx` library:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'Dark Red',  1: 'Scarlet Red',  2: 'Cherry Red',  3: 'Dark Blue',  4: 'Steel Blue',  5: 'Coral Blue',  6: 'Red',  7: 'Dark Red',  8: 'Blue',  9: 'Dark Blue',  10: 'Color',  11: 'Red',  12: 'Blue',  13: 'Dark',  14: 'Dark Red',  15: 'Dark Blue'}, 'Start': {0: 'P1',  1: 'C1',  2: 'C2',  3: 'P2',  4: 'C3',  5: 'C4',  6: 'L1',  7: 'P1',  8: 'L2',  9: 'P2',  10: 'LL1',  11: 'L1',  12: 'L2',  13: 'D1',  14: 'P1',  15: 'P2'}, 'End': {0: 'P1',  1: 'P1',  2: 'P1',  3: 'P2',  4: 'P2',  5: 'P2',  6: 'L1',  7: 'L1',  8: 'L2',  9: 'L2',  10: 'LL1',  11: 'LL1',  12: 'LL1',  13: 'D1',  14: 'D1',  15: 'D1'}})
dct = df.set_index('Start')['ID'].to_dict() # translate nodes to their names later on
```

**Code:**

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Start', 'End', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
T = nx.dfs_tree(G, source='C1').reverse()
print([dct.get(x) for x in T])
# Out: ['Scarlet Red', 'Dark Red', 'Red', 'Color', 'Dark']
```